# Model for two way table

Tags: regression, self-study, anova

Suppose you have data in the following format:

```
               <60 60-69 70-79 80-89 90-99
No Exercise      5   10     2    4    1
Moderate         2   4      12   4    3
Heavy            4   5      18   10   2
Extreme          5   6       7    9   12
```

The cells represent the number of people who died at that age range. Beside a chi square test, are there any other models that apply here? Would a poisson model be good here? Or could I just run a standard ANOVA? I want to test differences in death at different exercise levels.

Comment: Your frequency table is curious, because it could emerge under different studies, but you are silent about details. My imagination, for example, take it so that you recruited people aged 90-99 and forced them to exercise under different intensity levels. 12 died during extreme session, 2 died at heavy session, etc. 1 died just being reserved. But how many of the old men survived? You don't tell.

Comment: Basically at each level of exercise, you recruit 100 people aged 30 for each level.

Comment: Can you do survival analysis on this data?

Comment: @ttnphns I was thinking that for each age group the intensity of exercise is increased until death, so that the survivors from a moderate regime are then subjected to a heavy one & so on. (There are no survivors from the extreme regime.)

Comment: @Scortchi you may be right. But then - looking at the table - more senile cohorts proved to be more hale guys.

Comment: @ttnphns Perhaps it's a selection effect - only the more hale make it to be nonagenarians.

Comment: @Scortchi Right, and the 'incremental exercise' examination (conceivably the OP's project) may counterbalance the effect in the population.

Comment: @phil12 Sorry for the flippancy but there's a serious point: to suggest an appropriate analysis people need to know how the data were got, what they mean, & what you want to find out from them.

Answer (score 1):

> differences in death at difference exercise levels.

I'm pretty sure you mean differences in age at death.

Chi-square ignores the fact that both set of categories are ordered.

While you could use the middle of each interval as a proxy for age, ANOVA has the problem that these figures won't be normal, and what age would you use for a category like "<60"? Or are you going to code them some other way?

You probably want to check against some kind of location shift, perhaps with ordered alternatives. You might be able to use a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney in the first case or a Jonckheere-Terpstra type statistic in the second, but with allowance for the heavy ties (which would require, I suppose, simulating the null distribution of the test statistic, unless you can tolerate the approximation).

Comment: I have no problem using the middle of each interval. But do I have to utilize a nonparametric test or can I utilize some other simple parametric tests?

Comment: "Have to" isn't really applicable. You can do anything you like if you're prepared to live with the consequences. The assumptions of a normal theory test aren't satisfied; but if they're not close enough for your purposes you can use a similar analysis either with more suitable assumptions, whether you evaluate things algebraically or via simulation, or you could use resampling techniques, or as you suggest, nonparametric techniques. The major considerations relate to what questions you need to answer and the tradeoff between power and ease/simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinal logistic regression with age at death as the response and exercise regime as the predictor would save you having to code the age-ranges as a continuous variable - probably not a good idea with only five categories.

Plotting Kaplan-Meier survival curves & carrying out the log-rank test (an instance of survival analysis) would allow you to account for people who dropped out of the study (there must surely be some if you recruited them at 30 years old) or who are still alive.

Comment: Could you run  poisson regression to model the number of deaths?

Comment: @phil12 Yes - you might want to read something like [this](http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c5.pdf) about equivalencies between Poisson, binomial, & multinomial models applied to contingency tables.